# Chatter on Force.com site.?

Tags: apex, visualforce, chatter, force.com-sites

I want to use chatter feeds on Force.com sites.Its working fine inside VF page.Force.com its blank.

Is there any limitation?

Can you please help.?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the documentation link below

https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/related/Chatter+Components+for+Visualforce

Clearly from the above document

> Chatter components don't render for Visualforce pages using Force.com sites.

The Alternate solution would be to use Chatter REST API .You may need one license dedicated for this but with oauth ,you will be able to pull feeds and display

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_using_chatter_connect.htm