# Chatter in force.com sites

Tags: chatter

I have to use chatter in force.com sites. I have used `<chatter:feed entityId="{!$User.Id}"/>` in Vf page. Through VF pages if I click preview button I can see chatter page. See below  [image]

But When I am using this VF page in force.com site. It shows blank page.

How to use chatter in force.com site ?

Comment: A possible of duplicate of [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/89873/chatter-on-force-com-site) post.

Answer (score 1):

> Note that Chatter components don't render for Visualforce pages using
>   Force.com sites.

https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/related/Chatter+Components+for+Visualforce